# Dynamically selecting columns with parameter using Scala - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

**I need to dynamically select columns from one of the two tables I am joining. The name of one of the columns to be selected is passed to a variable.** Here are the details.

The table names are passed to variables. So is the join_id and the join_type.

```
//Creating scala variables for each table
var table_name_a = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name_a")
var table_name_b = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name_b")

//Create scala variable for Join Id
var join_id = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name_b") + "Id"

// Define join type
var join_type = dbutils.widgets.get("join_type")
```

Then, I join the tables. I want to select all columns from table A and only two columns from table B: one column is called "Description" no matter what table B is passed in the parameter above; the second column has the same name of the table B, e.g., if table B's name is Employee, I want to select a column named "Employee" from table B. The code below selects all columns from table A and the Description column from table B (aliased). But I still need to select another column from table B that has the same name as the table. I don't know in advance how many columns table B has in total nor column order or their names - since Table B is passed as a parameter.

```
// Joining Tables
var df_joined_tables = df_a
                                     .join(df_b,                                               
                                               df_a(join_id)===df_b(join_id),
                                              join_type
                                          ).select($"df_a.*",$"df_b.Description".alias(table_name_b + " Description"))
```

**My question is: How do I pass the variable table_name_b as a column I am trying to select from table B?**

I tried the code below which is obviously wrong because in "$"df_b.table_name_b" the "table_name_b" is supposed to be the content of the parameter and not the name of the columns itself.

```
var df_joined_tables = df_a
                                     .join(df_b,                                               
                                               df_a(join_id)===df_b(join_id),
                                              join_type
                                          ).select($"df_a.*",$"df_b.Description".alias(table_name_b + " Description"),$"df_b.table_name_b")
```

Then I tried the code below and it gives the error: "value table_name_b is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame"

```
var df_joined_tables = df_a
                                     .join(df_b,                                               
                                               df_a(join_id)===df_b(join_id),
                                              join_type
                                          ).select($"df_a.*",$"df_b.Description".alias(table_name_b + " Description"),df_b.table_name_b)
```

**How do I pass the variable table_name_b as a column I need to select from table B?**

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]` and use it on your `select` function like the below example:

```scala
// sample input:
val df = Seq(
  ("A", 1, 6, 7),
  ("B", 2, 7, 6),
  ("C", 3, 8, 5),
  ("D", 4, 9, 4),
  ("E", 5, 8, 3)
).toDF("name", "col1", "col2", "col3")

df.printSchema()
val columnNames = List("col1", "col2") // string column names from your params
val columnsToSelect = columnNames.map(col(_)) // convert the required column names from string to column type
df.select(columnsToSelect: _*).show() // using the list of columns

// output:
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   6|
|   2|   7|
|   3|   8|
|   4|   9|
|   5|   8|
+----+----+
```

Similarly can be applied for `join`'s

**Update**

Adding another example:

```scala
val aliasTableA = "tableA"
val aliasTableB = "tableB"
val joinField = "name"

val df1 = Seq(
  ("A", 1, 6, 7),
  ("B", 2, 7, 6),
  ("C", 3, 8, 5),
  ("D", 4, 9, 4),
  ("E", 5, 8, 3)
).toDF("name", "col1", "col2", "col3")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("A", 11, 61, 71),
  ("B", 21, 71, 61),
  ("C", 31, 81, 51)
).toDF("name", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3")


df1.alias(aliasTableA)
  .join(df2.alias(aliasTableB), Seq(joinField))
  .selectExpr(s"${aliasTableA}.*", s"${aliasTableB}.col_1", s"${aliasTableB}.col_2").show()

// output:
+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|name|col1|col2|col3|col_1|col_2|
+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|   A|   1|   6|   7|   11|   61|
|   B|   2|   7|   6|   21|   71|
|   C|   3|   8|   5|   31|   81|
+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Interesting! However, I don't know how many columns table B will have since it is passed as a parameter. Each table passed as Table B can have a different number of columns that I don't know in advance.

Comment: my mistake, I've added a better example for your use case. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It is a bit late here, I will try it on Monday and let you know :)

Comment: Your updated example is nice but I am not sure this is what I need but I am new to Spark/Scala. Might be a dumb question but is the "val df1 = Seq(" part just an example or do I need to code each table using it? If so, the problem is that I don't know how many columns each table will have nor their names (since they will be dynamically passed as a parameter to the notebook).

Comment: `val df1 = Seq(...).toDF()` is a way to create a `Dataframe` programmatically. In this case `d1` will be your `df_a` (your dataframe). In your question you mentioned that you need to select all the columns from one table, this is done by `.selectExpr(s"${aliasTableA}.*"`, where you only need to specify the alias for that table.

Comment: Actually, with your current code it might work if you add the alias to your `Dataframes` in a similar way that I've added in the example.